# Cannot use Bacula after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, services

I upgraded my server to Ubuntu 16.04 lately and since then, I cannot use bconsole anymore.  There seems to be a problem in the director configuration.  I noticed that in `/etc/init.d`, there was a file called `bacula-director` and not `bacula-dir` as I read in the documentation ([Bacula documentation](http://www.bacula.org/7.2.x-manuals/en/main/Brief_Tutorial.html#SECTION001430000000000000000)).
If I try to run bacula-dir as documented, I get, logically:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart bacula-dir
Failed to restart bacula-dir.service: Unit bacula-dir.service not found.
```

Running bacula-director starts correctly, although it gives this strange this strange `Bad; vendor preset` (which is also present if I issue the same command on other services like apache2, apport, etc - so I do not think this is the problem):

```
$ sudo systemctl restart bacula-director
$ sudo systemctl status bacula-director
● bacula-director.service - LSB: Start Bacula Director at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/bacula-director; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since lun 2016-08-22 15:15:45 CEST; 14s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 31465 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/bacula-director stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31476 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/bacula-director start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

aoû 22 15:15:45 servex systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start Bacula Director at boot time.
aoû 22 15:15:45 servex systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Bacula Director at boot time...
aoû 22 15:15:45 servex bacula-director[31476]:  * Starting Bacula Director... bacula-dir
aoû 22 15:15:45 servex bacula-director[31476]:    ...done.
aoû 22 15:15:45 servex systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Bacula Director at boot time.
```

If I run bacula-dir directly, I end up with the following:

`$ sudo bacula-dir -tvd99
bacula-dir: dird.c:194-0 Debug level = 99
bacula-dir: address_conf.c:264-0 Initaddr 0.0.0.0:9101
bacula-dir: dir_plugins.c:148-0 Load dir plugins
bacula-dir: dir_plugins.c:150-0 No dir plugin dir!
bacula-dir: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/bacula/libbaccats-7.0.5.so: undefined symbol: mysql_init`

But I cannot use the console:

```
$ sudo bconsole
Connecting to Director localhost:9101
$
```

Any hint to get the system up and running again?

Answer (score 0):

Add following line to the file /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
```

Then do

```
apt-get update
```

then

```
apt-get install bacula/xenial-proposed
```

Comment: Why would this solve the problem?

Comment: I can't believe this bug hasn't been corrected yet. The released bacula version has multiple issues preventing it from working, or at least working reliably. The bug has been reported and accepted and fixex in xenial-proposed.. but still no release. Doing what Arthur says will fix bacula, but then if you don't remove the line you'll get many more proposed updates (including kernels every few days, usually). So after you have fixed your bacula you can comment the line and run apt-get update again (or at least, that's what I'm doing)

Comment: @RobM: Unfortunately, it is so: there still is no change in the current depot for Xenial.  Anyway, thank you for your explanation.  I am reluctant though to install the 'proposed' ppa in my list as I fear it could break other things.  This is something to be done with care, I think.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen, I agree: what I did was to enable proposed, update *only* Bacula, then disable proposed again. That way nothing else gets upgraded.
A friend of mine suggested to switch to Bareos (a Bacula fork) but I still need to back up some 14.04 and I don't have time to see if I can compile it for those.

Comment: @RobM: This problem is now SOLVED: a correct version has been made available and works (tried 1 hour ago).